# Smooth transition on menu show and collapsed

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I would like to implement a transition with **tailwincss** , on 'active' state change, I mean when the menu is shown/collapsed i would like to implement a smooth and pleasing transition

I tried adding it on the state change by adding `transition delay-150 duration-300 ease-in-out` but i couldn't make it work.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import HamburgerMenu from "react-hamburger-menu";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const NavLink = dynamic(() => import("./NavLink"));

export const Navbar = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setActive(!active);
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setActive(false);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="sticky top-0 z-10 flex flex-wrap items-center px-3 py-3 bg-white md:py-3 container bg-red-200">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between w-full">
        <Link href="/">
          <a className="inline-flex items-center">
            <span className="text-xl font-bold tracking-wide text-black tahu">
              Agoumi.
            </span>
          </a>
        </Link>
        <div className="inline-flex p-0 ml-auto text-xl rounded-full outline-none hover:shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-black">
          <HamburgerMenu
            isOpen={isOpen}
            menuClicked={handleClick}
            width={20}
            height={15}
            strokeWidth={2}
            rotate={0}
            color="black"
            // borderRadius={15}
            animationDuration={1}
            className="m-3"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`${
          active ? "transition delay-150 duration-300 ease-in-out" : "hidden"
        } w-full`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col items-start w-full align-center">
          <NavLink close={handleClose} to="/" linkName="Home" isOpen={false} />
          <NavLink
            close={handleClose}
            to="about"
            linkName="About Me"
            isOpen={false}
          />
          <NavLink
            close={handleClose}
            to="value"
            linkName="Values"
            isOpen={false}
          />
          <NavLink
            close={handleClose}
            to="projects"
            linkName="Projects"
            isOpen={false}
          />
          <NavLink
            close={handleClose}
            to="contact"
            linkName="Contact us"
            isOpen={false}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the `display` property (via the `hidden` class) cannot be animated, you can see the whole list of animatable properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

You can animate `height`, but it requires specifying the full menu height explicitly (`auto` will not animate), so `h-32` in the code below is just an example, you may need to change it depending on your exact circumstances.

Here's an example:

```
      <div
        className={`${
          active ? 'h-32' : 'h-0'
        } transition-all delay-150 duration-300 overflow-hidden w-full`}
      >
      ...
```

Note that `transition-all` is used, simple `transition` will not animate `height`, and `ease-in-out` is removed, as it is redundant, the same timing function is already included in `transition-all`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explenation.